# autocomplete search in cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, json, autocomplete

```
$( "#skills" ).autocomplete({source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON("http://server/current/indrealestates.com/properties/autosuggesthome/",{ term:request.term ,extraParams:$('#property_id').val()}, 
    response
        );
    },
    minLength: 2,
    focus:function(event, ui){$("#skills").val(ui.item.label);return false},
    select: function(event, ui){
        $("#skills").val(ui.item.label);$("#project-id").val(ui.item.value);
        window.location.href=ui.item.value+"/";
        return false
    }
});
```

i want to add also result not found show when response null.currently this code run but not result found do not show please suggest how to improve this code

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the response is empty or not in getJSON & add the message.

**e.g**

```
 if(response.length > 0)
     {...}
 else
     {...}
```